# Mega Dropdown menu seen on sitepoint

Tags: jquery, menu

Im busy messing around with the mega menu example shown on [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/03/31/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/) but noticed it uses a plugin to delay the hover. How do i adjust the Jquery so that i don't use the plugin. Sorry I can't figure it out my code so far

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

  function addsubmenu(){
    $(this).addClass("hovering");
    $(".hovering div").animate({"opacity": "toggle"}, { duration: "slow" });
    }

  function removesubmenu(){
    $(this).removeClass("hovering");
    }
});
```

but its not doing anything

Comment: make it sleep, and on the callback, check if there's still a hover and display the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really avoid using HoverIntent here, since this is essentially the "spine" of the script functionality, the 'hover' behaviour is enabled by it.

If you want custom animations on the submenu items, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function addsubmenu(){
        $(this).animate({"opacity": "toggle"}, { duration: "slow" });
    }
    function removesubmenu(){
        $(this).animate({"opacity": "toggle"}, { duration: "fast" });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I dedcide in the end to use the plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-mega-menu/

Its simple fast and easy to configure